# How to efficiently set CSS properties for all browser (-webkit, -moz, -o, -ms) with angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

I need to set a CSS property using an angular function.
Here is my code:

```
<div ng-style="{ 'transform': getRotation(i) }"></div>
```

However, I'd like to add browser compatibility using the following properties:

- -webkit-transform
- -moz-transform
- -ms-transform
- -o-transform

I tried something like :

```
 ng-style="{ 'transform': getRotation(i),
             '-webkit-transform': getRotation(i),
             '-moz-transform': getRotation(i),
             '-ms-transform': getRotation(i),
             '-o-transform': getRotation(i) }"
```

But `getRotation()` is called five times even if only one property is needed.

Do you know of to properly and efficiently manage CSS compatibility with angular?

**EDIT:** Working [plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/qnbtbdvTfqCF8imEfma6?p=preview) if needed

Comment: Maybe this is a good choice: https://www.npmjs.com/package/inline-style-prefixer

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a precompilation tool, such as gulp or grunt, you can create a class with your transform property and use an auto-prefixer that will generate all the prefix properties. Then, you just have to use ng-class instead of ng-style.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write a directive to reduce the number of times getRotation() function gets called.

The directive should generate the style attribute by watching getRotation and update the style attribute only once instead of 5 times.

Please share your code in plunker or something, so I can update it with the directive.

Edit:
The below plunker contains the directive I mentioned above.

https://plnkr.co/edit/iodBM1zbmrRGuNT8J0R9?p=preview

```
.directive('prefixTransform', function($log) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        prefixTransform: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element) {
        scope.$watch('prefixTransform', function(o, n) {
          element
            .css('transform', n)
            .css('-webkit-transform', n)
            .css('-moz-transform', n)
            .css('-ms-transform', n)
            .css('-o-transform', n);
        });
      }
    };
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here is a plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/qnbtbdvTfqCF8imEfma6?p=preview

Comment: @Alex, Thanks for the plunker, Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

use ng-class instead of ng-style
use transform function in css.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how to get dynamic properties using ng-class? Because my "transform" is not a fixed number.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a the [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) instead of ng-style. It's a lot cleaner than the inline styling and it allows you to use a CSS preprocessor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/guide) to define all cross browser style prefixes through mixin functions.